# How to measure the runtime of each operator in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, runtime, bigdata, profiling

Is there a way to measure the runtime of each operator in Spark

For example I have the following word count code:

```
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
             .map(word => (word, 1))
             .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

How to measure the runtime for each of the map/flatMap/reduceByKey operators individually?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something strange like create [accumulators](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-accumulators.html) for each transformation and accumulate time there.
[Here](http://biercoff.com/easily-measuring-code-execution-time-in-scala/) is code for time measurement.
Just use it to measure time for each single operation and add value to accumulator.

**BUT THAT IS REALLY STRANGE APPROACH**

First of all - all transformation are converted into tasks that are then sent to workers for execution. It might be even that multiple transformation are in a same task.

So i think what you want - is to use [Spark Web UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

Comment: Thank you, I think accumulators might work, I will try it. I tried the Spark Web UI but it does not give the required information, it shows the runtime for the whole task which might be consist of multiple operators as you said.